# Porting 64bit code to 32bit machine

Tags: c, x86-64, porting, i386

I have seen many people asking porting issues from 32bit to 64bit machine. But is it not common to port code written on 64bit to 32bit. I am trying to port a plugin from 64bit to 32bit in C,but facing similar issues in cases like storing void * to 64bit integers and vice versa.

Whats should be approach in changing the code such that same code works on both(i386 & x86_64) machines? I don't think it make sense to use uint64_t * on a 32 bit machine in place of void* which is 32bit? Does some generalized approach exists for such cases?

Comment: Pointers should never be stored in fixed-size integers. If you need to store a pointer in an integer type, the correct type is `uintptr_t`, but you really should not be storing pointers in integer objects at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers should never be stored in fixed-size integers. If you need to store a pointer in an integer type, the correct type is `uintptr_t`, but you really should not be storing pointers in integer objects at all. **However**, there's no real harm in using an integer type that's too large; it will just waste a little bit of memory. So if storing pointers in `uint64_t` is the only issue in your code, it should work fine compiled for 32-bit targets.

Comment: Thanks, So in cases where a `uint64_t` is typecasted to `void*` we should just replace it with `uintprt_t` and all warnings should go away without any side effects on both architectures. Actually in my case the address are stored in integers because later these are used for comparision.

Comment: The code should work as-is. I'm not sure what you mean by "replace it with `uintptr_t`, so please clarify.

Comment: Finally, I am able to solve this problem by replacing all the integers which are storing addresses to `uintptr_t` inplace of `uint64_t`and did similar stuff during typecasting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, You can write one source code for both 32bit and 64bit architectures with a series of "#define", "#ifdef" etc which are pre-processor directives. You need to compile the source once for 32bit and 64bit each. This can be something like this.

test.c sample code

```
#ifdef ARCH_64
    typedef UINT unit64_t;
#else
    typedef UINT unit32_2;

UINT  *my_uint_ptr;
```

$ gcc -m32 test.c

$ gcc -m64 -DARCH_64 test.c

Comment: If we need to define `unsigned int`  then this can be done very easily by just using `size_t` and it will automatically be substituted correctly by compiler depending on architecture.

Comment: That is True. I am only giving an example for way of writing one source code for both 32bit and 64bit and compiling it...